# firebase deploying cloub function v2 Unknown name "allowInsecure"

Tags: node.js, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I was upgrading from firebase function from v1 to v2 and while deploying anyone knows what wrong? i did npm run build && firebase emulators:start --only functions and and the function runs and works

> HTTP Error: 400, Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "allowInsecure" at 'function.https_trigger': Cannot find field

code

```
exports.crawlPlatforms = FunctionsV2
    .https
    .onRequest( async (req:any, res:any) => {
        res.send(await CrawlPlatforms());
    });


const CrawlPlatforms = async () => {
    console.log("CrawlPlatform: Start!");
    return "Success";
};
```

Comment: What's CrawlPlatforms?  There seems to be a whole lot missing here.  Please edit the question to provide a [minimal complete example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of code that anyone can use to reproduce the issue as you observe it.  We should be able to simply copy and paste the code with your instructions.

Comment: just sending back a success